# Magento 2 UpgradeData doesn't work

Tags: database, table

I made a simple module wich create a simple table.
This is my module.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../lib/internal/Magento/Framework/Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="Tutorial_TutorialTable" setup_version="1.0.0" active="true">

</module>
</config>
```

This is my InstallSchema.php under Tutorial/TutorialTable/Setup/

```
<?php

namespace Tutorial\TutorialTable\Setup;

use Magento\Framework\Setup\InstallSchemaInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\SchemaSetupInterface;
use Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table;

    class InstallSchema implements InstallSchemaInterface
    {
        public function install(SchemaSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context)
        {
            $installer = $setup;
            $installer->startSetup();

            // Get tutorial_simplenews table
            $tableName = $installer->getTable('tutorial_simplenews');
            // Check if the table already exists
            if ($installer->getConnection()->isTableExists($tableName) != true) {
                // Create tutorial_simplenews table
                $table = $installer->getConnection()
                    ->newTable($tableName)
                    ->addColumn(
                        'id',
                        Table::TYPE_INTEGER,
                        null,
                        [
                            'identity' => true,
                            'unsigned' => true,
                            'nullable' => false,
                            'primary' => true
                        ],
                        'ID'
                    )
```

and so on...

The table is correctly created.

Now I want to use UpgradeData.php to insert into table something and I add UpgradeData.php under Tutorial/TutorialTable/Setup

```
<?php

namespace Tutorial\TutorialTable\Setup;

use Magento\Framework\Setup\UpgradeDataInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;

class UpgradeData implements UpgradeDataInterface
{
    public function upgrade(
        ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup,
        ModuleContextInterface $context
    ) {
        $setup->startSetup();
        if (version_compare($context->getVersion(), '1.0.1') == 0) {
            // Get tutorial_simplenews table
            $tableName = $setup->getTable('tutorial_simplenews');
            // Check if the table already exists
            if ($setup->getConnection()->isTableExists($tableName) == true) {
```

.. add some data in $data array .. and then

```
   foreach ($data as $item) {
                    $setup->getConnection()->insert($tableName, $item);
                }
            }
        }

        $setup->endSetup();
    }
}
```

Si i edit the setup_version in my module.xml

```
setup_version="1.0.1"
```

and then i run

> php bin/magento setup:upgrade

And all module is correctly load but i don't have any data in my table.
Where i'm wrong?
Thanks in advice.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think this is the problem

```
if (version_compare($context->getVersion(), '1.0.1') == 0) {
```

it should be

```
if (version_compare($context->getVersion(), '1.0.1') < 0) {
```

because when you run the upgradeData file the version is still `1.0.0` and it becomes 1.0.1 only after the upgrade is done.

Comment: You can even use the third parameter of version_compare:  `(version_compare($context->getVersion(), '1.0.1','<')`