# Adding Products Attributes Programatically?

Tags: magento-2.1.7

I want to add product attributes programmatically. I did for one attribute and I want to add another attribute. It is not working when I wrote the code like below :

```
class InstallData implements InstallDataInterface
{
private $eavSetupFactory;

public function __construct(EavSetupFactory $eavSetupFactory)
{
    $this->eavSetupFactory = $eavSetupFactory;
}

public function install(ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context)
{
    $eavSetup = $this->eavSetupFactory->create(['setup' => $setup]);
    $eavSetup->addAttribute(
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product::ENTITY,
        'sample_attribute',
        [
            'type' => 'text','backend' => '','frontend' => '','label' => 'Sample Atrribute',
            'input' => 'text',
            'global' => \Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\ScopedAttributeInterface::SCOPE_GLOBAL,
            'visible' => true,
            'required' => true,
            'user_defined' => false,'default' => '','visible_on_front' => false,
            'used_in_product_listing' => true,
            'unique' => false,
            'apply_to' => ''
        ]
        );
    $eavSetup->addAttribute(
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product::ENTITY,
        'sample_attribute1',
        [
            'type' => 'text',
            'backend' => '','frontend' => '','label' => 'Sample Atrribute',
            'input' => 'text',
            'global' => \Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\ScopedAttributeInterface::SCOPE_GLOBAL,
            'visible' => true,'required' => true,'user_defined' => false,
            'default' => '',
            'visible_on_front' => false,
            'used_in_product_listing' => true,
            'unique' => false,
            'apply_to' => ''
        ]
    );
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In this case you need `UpgradeSchema` instead, `InstallData` is used when you install module for the first run and aims to insert data into database.

For more information [here](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/179119/difference-between-installschema-and-installdata)

Answer (score 0):

You are correct that you use data (and not schema), but as mentioned in the other answer, you have to create a file called `UpgradeData.php`. `InstallData.php` is only used when the module is installed for the first time.

This question & answer should work as a reference: [Magento 2 UpgradeData doesn't work](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/101422/magento-2-upgradedata-doesnt-work)